# Module not recognized in Xcode Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a Xcode project with some Objective-C++ code, and Swift code.
To use Swift classes in Objective-C, I had to import the "ProductName-Swift.h" but when creating this file and compiling it, it gave errors because import aren't done : 
[image: error]

so, after a while I found it is the :

```
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
...
#endif
```

and precisely the "__has_feature(modules)" that doesn't work...
Whereas I activated it in the build options !

[image: module settings]

I use Xcode 6.2. Is it fixed on 6.3 ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi, I got a explanation from Apple at the previous WWDC : Objective-C++ doesn't support modules like Objective-C does, so for Objective-C++, ```__has_feature(modules)``` doesn't work. I found a workaround, but don't know if it'll work for you : add the "ProductName-Swift.h" to your project like your others files : we'll gonna edit it, and if you add it this way, it'll override the generated one. Then, remove the has_feature(modules) from the line, (near 65 for me) and change the @import to regular #import until the #endif